Spring CriteriaBuilder Number to String cast results in casting 4000 char varchar2 in SQL statement
I am creating a Specification that can do partial searches on numbers. My overridden toPredicate method:
/** The not. */
    @Builder.Default
    boolean not = false;

    /** The property. */
    @Builder.Default
    String property = "";

    /** The value. */
    @Builder.Default
    String value = "";

       .......

 @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {
        if (!this.value.contains("%"))
            this.value = "%" + this.value + "%";

        if (this.not)
            return builder.notLike(root.get(this.property).as(String.class), this.value, '\'');
        else
            return builder.like(root.get(this.property).as(String.class), this.value, '\'');
    }

which results in this where clause:
select * from customer where cast(cust_number as varchar2(4000 char)) .....

I am concerned casting the number to a 4000 char varchar2 on the database side will become a performance issue on bigger data sets.
Is there a way to limit the number of characters the system sets or use a different datatype on the Java side?
